# How to avoid "declared but not used" error in for loop variables?

Tags: for-loop, go

I am new to Go. And this "declared but not used" error is really something. I mean, annoying.

Here is my code:

```
func addBorder(a []string) []string {
    var result []string
    wall := ""

    for i := range a {
        newElement := "*" + a[i] + "*"
        fmt.Println(newElement)
        result = append(result, newElement)
    }

    for i := range a[0] {
        wall += "*"
    }

    result = append([]string{wall}, result...)

    return result
}
```

The problem is the second for loop. It keeps saying that "i declared but not used" all the time and no idea how to deal with it. I don't really need it besides using it to iterate. Adding `i += 0` solved it but that is definitely not a good way to deal with this problem. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In second for loop, you can code like that:

```
for range a[0] {
    wall += "*"
}
```